# spring boot set embedded container tcp options

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp

I use spring boot and undertow in eureka server. After I kill the process, it tells me the port is in use when I restart the applicaiton.

I searched and finded that `the server application won't release the port immediately after stopping . It will wait about 50s`.

Someone suggested to add REUSE option:
`setsockopt(listenfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&opt,sizeof(&opt));`

I am wondering if there is a way to to this in spring boot embedded containers.

Thanks.

Comment: Try stopping `javaw` process from the task manager

Comment: @PRATHAPS Don't understand. I start application `java -jar` this way

Comment: If you are windows, run `netstat -a -o -n` identify the process id running on the port, kill the process forcibly `taskkill /F /PID <above-prorcess-id>`. If you are on mac, run `lsof -i:<portnum>`, identify the process id then run `kill <process-id>`. This should release the port and start your java app.

Comment: @harshavmb I am on linux. I kill the process and start application in a script. It tells me the port is in use.

Comment: I found an alternative way to release the port. Add -9(`kill -9 <process-id>`) it can work.